# Can quotes be used in css selectors for class names?

Tags: css

Here it is:

```
.color-expo svg .color-main-1 .x-comp path ".tick-1" {
   fill: #aeb24a;
}
```

I'm generating this with a third-party tool and I wonder if the quoted class is valid css. I'm only interested in knowing if the selector is valid.

Comment: No, it wouldn't work.

Comment: This is not a valid CSS!

Comment: what is it supposed to mean ? Just like if the quotes weren't here ? That "third-party tool" is retarded or not properly used.

Comment: Why are you doing it?

Comment: Great! That's what I thought.

Comment: Now I wonder what'll happen if you just remove the quotation marks. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That's not valid in pure css.

---

I think that plugin might be saying to use your class there like `.tick-1` or `.someclass` but you need to check your html markup by inspecting before using it that what class would be rendered by that plugin:

```
.color-expo svg .color-main-1 .x-comp path .tick-1 {
   fill: #aeb24a;
}
```

Comment: It's not just a comment, it's the answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

From the W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) Official [CSS 2.1 Specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters):

> **4.1.3 Characters and Case**: In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Selectors cannot contain quotation marks. That said, you are using quotation marks *around* the selector, rather than as part of the selector. I'm not sure what effect you hoped to achieve by this, but it is also not valid.